# Amazon EC2 - PHP GD image library

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, gd

I've got a brand new install of WordPress setup and activated a custom-built theme along with a good amount of plugins. In the posts, I have built it so the user can create a post, upload an image as a thumbnail and it will automatically resize the image to a custom size set in my functions.php file.

All this has been working on my local end (MAMP) correctly but when I tried making everything work on our Amazon EC2 server, the images do not resize to the size set. They resize by actual code but do not resize the actual image and save it in the new size.

Apologies if the question/subject is completely non-sense but I have little to no experience with Amazon EC2 servers and I have been placed into a situation where the person in charge of all the work within EC2 had to leave the project.

I'm assuming that this has to do with the GD library not being installed.. I created a test page with phpinfo() and didn't see a GD area on the results page.

How would I go about installing the library on my Amazon EC2 server? I just learned how to connect to the server via Terminal and that's all I've got for now.. so you get an idea of how much I know about the subject.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I'm guessing you have some type of Linux installed, probably Ubuntu or CentOS.

Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install php5-gd`
CentOS: `sudo yum install php-gd`

You probably have to restart Apache afterwards: `service httpd restart` or `service apache2 restart` -- the names differ from distribution to distribution.

Let me know if this works!

Comment: I'll give it ago.. Do I do this install anywhere specifically.. Within the folders that hold my WordPress install or in the root of my whole EC2 setup?

Comment: You have to log into the EC2 instance using SSH. And then execute the commands. Either uses the distributions package manager to install a package with GD. I forgot to _write_ `sudo` before the last two, you'll need it there as well.

Comment: Perfect! I logged in via Terminal using SSH and used the yum command (since I had Yum installed instead of apt-get) to install the library in the root of my EC2 server. After that, I restarted using the httpd approach. I created a test page with phpinfo and GD was shown as enabled!

Answer (score 28):

In my case, I was getting error like there is version conflict between different versions of php-common when I entered "yum install php-gd" so I checked my php version using "php -v" in shell and then installed the corresponding gd using "yum install php56-gd" because I had php 5.6 installed in my machine.

Hope someone will get help from this.

Cheers

Answer (score 11):

to avoid compatibility problems first do:

```
php --version
```

to know your php version

the answer is something in the form PHP X.Y.Z

so you have to take X, Y and do:

```
sudo yum install phpXY-gd
```

for instance if php --version says PHP 5.5.26

you will do:

```
sudo yum install php55-gd
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for - thank you! `sudo yum install php56-gd` and it worked perfect.

Answer (score 10):

In my case of ec2 server running Amazon Linux 2 with php version 7.2.24, following was the sequence:

```
sudo yum install php-gd
```

But event after repeat server restart with

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

it was not working unless I rebooted with

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro I the reboot part was very useful and nowhere to be found

Comment: It's not necessary to reboot, you can do `sudo systemctl restart php-fpm` to load the new module.

Answer (score 0):

In Amazon Linux, we have to add the following line to the etc/php.ini file

`extension=gd.so`

Step 1: Install the package using following command

`sudo yum install php-gd`

Step 2: Include the following line to the etc/php.ini file

`extension=gd.so`

If the line is commented, then uncomment it.

Step 3: Restart the httpd service

`sudo service httpd restart`