# Wordpress image thumbnails are not being created

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, thumbnails

I think this is more than a plugin or install issue, I think it may be a server issue.

Basically when I upload any image, say filename.jpg, the typical filename-150x150.jpg thumbnail version of the image is not being created in my uploads folder beside the original. But there are no upload errors, all goes through fine. But when I need the thumbnail somewhere in the code, it's not finding one (and I don't see it in the uploads folder, although I see the original file there).

I'm on Amazon EC2 (AMI) running your typical Wordpress setup (PHP 5.3.29, MySQL, Apache).

Any ideas on why these thumbnails might not be getting created, or where I could search for any errors happening?

Comment: Is the GD library installed?

Comment: Actually just checked that, dumped phpinfo and nothing about GD was in there.

Comment: I have never used Amazon EC2, but it sounds like this is fairly common. Check out this other SO answer for the commands to install GD library. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117505/amazon-ec2-php-gd-image-library

Comment: That was the answer, installed PHP GD and restarted Apache, all good now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears PHP GD wasn't installed.

Ran these two commands:

```
sudo yum install php-gd
sudo service httpd restart
```

And then used the Regenerate Thumbnails plugin to regenerate my thumbnails and everything worked.

Thanks to @Quantastical for the help.

Comment: For future visitors, if using Ubuntu flavor of Linux, use the following command: `sudo apt-get install php5-gd`